# If key pressed after an input clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if the user clicked the input and after that pressed the enter key:

```
$('#AdsData tr td input').live('keypress', function (e) {
    // if the Enter key is presses
    if (e.which == 13) {

    }
});
```

I tried it: clicked an input and pressed enter but the function wasn't called..

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live` no longer exists in the most up to date version, you need to use `on` with a delegate instead in that case.

Comment: Is the function called if you press something other than enter?

Comment: my version has the live.. when I did:
$('#AdsData tr td input').live('click', function (e) {
    alert('3');
});

the click works..

Comment: Why not just disable the button when it's clicked?

Comment: I don't want to disable it :/ thank you..

Comment: You should use keydown instead of keypress. I'm pretty sure keypress might behave differently across browsers.

Comment: keydown doesn't work.. exactly for keyup..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you can try doing with `e.which and e.keyCode` both this way:

```
var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (kc == 13) {
```

and instead of `keypress` try with `keyup` or `keydown`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input').keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        alert('Enter.');
    }
});
```

Comment: When you said "clicked an input", you means a textfield or a button ?

Answer (score 1):

if the input element is part of a form, pressing enter will most likely submit the form. in that case try this:

```
$("#your_form").on("submit", function() {});
```